# how can i resolve this kind of error in VB.net? MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your Sql syntax; check the manual...'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

```
Private connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=hotelmanagementdb")

    ReadOnly Property getConnection() As MySqlConnection
        Get
            Return connection
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub openConnection()
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub closeConnection()
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            connection.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

the error at the adapter.Fill(table)
throwing an error to check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`password`=''' at line 1 
Ive been constantly updating my MySql ports in Xampp due to errors, i guess this is the reason why some errors occurs

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have an error in your SQL syntax and yet you haven't even shown us the SQL code, which suggests that you haven't even looked at it yourself. There are certain basic things that you are expected to do before posting here and when posting here. Looking at your own code and providing us with the relevant code fall under those categories.

Answer (score 0):

on mysql password please do not null in password.

if your mysql don't have password please set,  `Password='';`

Comment: Same error as usual MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`password`=''' at line 1'